# crystal reports DataSet does not support System.Nullable

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

[image]

> Additional information: DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

Error in crystal report at line

```
rd.SetDataSource(allCustomer);
```

Comment: please show the code where you make allCostomer variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crystal Reports doesn't currently support nullable-types. It seems your type of `allCustomer` contains at least one property with a nullable, like `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`, causing the error to throw. (You can read more about this in the [Microsoft documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9788f39c-2f3a-489d-8586-e7fc7c429e3b/crystal-does-not-support-systemnullable?forum=vscrystalreports))

Create a type like `allCustomer` has, but without nullable-typed properties:

```
int? -> int
float? -> float
DateTime? -> DateTime
....
```

You can use any .NET object mapping library, such as Automapper, to map old types into Crystal-compatible ones.

Comment: Matthias Burger : Thank you very much

Comment: @PrashantChoudhary glad I could help :)